# iPhone + Twitter API: Converting time?

Tags: iphone, twitter

Is there an easy way to convert the time stamp you get from twitter into unix time or minutes since now? I could parse through the string and convert everything myself but I'm hoping there is a way to convert that doesn't need that. Here is an example of a created_at element with a time stamp.

Sun Mar 18 06:42:26 +0000 2007

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use NSDateFormatter with something like this :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale]; 
[usLocale release];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];

// see http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[currentDict objectForKey:@"created_at"]];
[dateFormatter release];

NSTimeInterval seconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: This is also partly wrong too! The creation of an NSDateFormatter object is pretty heavy, so make it a static, or make it an ivar whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have been strugeling with this all day, but this thread helped me to find a solution.

This is how I convert the Twitter "created_at" attribute to a NSDATE;

```
NSDateFormatter *fromTwitter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// here we set the DateFormat  - note the quotes around +0000
[fromTwitter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss '+0000' yyyy"];
// We need to set the locale to english - since the day- and month-names are in english
[fromTwitter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];

NSString *dateString = [item objectForKey:@"created_at"];
NSDate *tweetedDate = [fromTwitter dateFromString:dateString];
```

I hope someone will find this helpful.

Comment: ZOMG thank you it works! Found 5 other formats that didn't work. The key seems to be the locale which everyone else seems to have missed.

Answer (score 0):

File a feature request with Apple and let them know you want this functionality on the iPhone. NSDateFormatter provides a legacy init method that takes a boolean flag indicating you want it to parse natural language, but it's only available on OS X. Wil Shipley wrote an [interesting post](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2009/08/pimp-my-code-part-16-heuristics-and.html) a while back about this functionality in the context of heuristics and human factors.

It doesn't seem likely that Apple will provide this functionality as this note would indicate from the [NSDateFormatter docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-DontLinkElementID_1):

> iPhone OS Note: iPhone OS supports
>   only the 10.4+ behavior. 10.0-style
>   methods and format strings are not
>   available on iPhone OS.

In other words, I think you'll have to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something like: [ISO 8601 parser and unparser](http://boredzo.org/iso8601parser/).

Comment: The format of the example provided in the question is not ISO 8601.