# Comparison of Date/Time with unknown format

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have to time value in output

First is :=

"updated_time" = 1308318422;  (Unix timestamp, returning from "stream" table from facebook)

Second is :=

"created_at" = "Thu Jul 14 15:24:51 +0000 2011";  ( This is time of Twitter post, I don't what type of format it is).

I have to compare both date/time. I have to list most recent will come first and so on.

What is the logic? Code preference will be appreciate :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Convert both values to `NSDate` objects and then use the `compare:` method.

The first can be converted by getting the int value of the updated_time and then using `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:updatedTimeInt]`.

The second can be converted with an `NSDateFormatter` object.

Comment: Can you help me in coding also ? I am new in iphone .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002544/iphone-twitter-api-converting-time here is good resource