# How to Parse Month and Year from Twitter API returned JSON

Tags: iphone, json, twitter, nsdateformatter

Suppose Twitter returns `Wed Sep 14 18:52:57 +0000 2011`in JSON format. How do i go about parsing it so that the display looks something like `Sep 2011`.
 Im aware of `DateFormatter`. I tried the following code  but it keeps returning me `Null`.

```
NSString *created = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"created_at"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:created];
   tweetingSince.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[dateFormatter    stringFromDate:date]];
```

Comment: if you have same string format always than just explode the string and get that value that you want to display from your string

Comment: You mean pick the substrings from a string via `NSMakeRange` or something.. Im not too sure but I don't believe Twitter will change the format anytime soon.. worth giving a try!!

Comment: Yes you can do it like that check my answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same date format to parse the input string `created` to `NSDate` and to create final output format from the parsed date. Date formatter is unable to parse date `Wed Sep 14 18:52:57 +0000 2011` using date format `MMM yyyy`. This is why the `date` is nil.

Edit:
Also quick googling gave me this result on SO: [iPhone + Twitter API: Converting time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002544/iphone-twitter-api-converting-time)

Edit 2: Your code with proper `NSDate` parsing would look like this

```
NSString *created = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"created_at"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
//  Parse input string to NSDate
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:created];
//  Convert parsed date to output format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];
tweetingSince.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[dateFormatter    stringFromDate:date]];
```

Comment: hmmm youre right Lukas!! Stupid me.. though i have no idea how it needs to be done

Comment: I wonder why google never throws up nice searches for me :D!! Tried and Tested this.. It works like a charm!! Thanks mate!!

Comment: Thanks Dilip. I like you answer for its elegance and easiness, it would definitely satisfy holier's needs ;-) `NSDate` would be really useful when the app would be localized for example

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
NSString *myString = @"Wed Sep 14 18:52:57 +0000 2011";

    NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
    NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];

    NSLog(@"dilip-%@",components);
```

Output will be

```
dilip-(
    Wed,
    Sep,
    14,
    "18:52:57",
    "+0000",
    2011
)
```

Now you can select any value from array and create new string using that value.

```
NSString * firstStr = [components objectAtIndex:1];
NSString * secondStr = [components objectAtIndex:5];


NSString * fullStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstStr,secondStr];

NSLog(@"dilip - %@",fullStr);
```

Output will be

```
dilip - Sep 2011
```

Comment: sorry for taking the green tick away from you!!! I believe that below mentioned was more suitable to my coding style!! 

But If any one is reading this : This answer is perfectly legitimate!!

Comment: No problem. Good answer must be appreciated and Lukas had given nice answer.

Comment: Btw your solution could be one-liner by using `NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]` ;-)